# Problem using Dropbox API in python with OAuth2 code

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I am trying to set up an app using Dropbox as the medium for users to share files.

I am able to upload a file using the App token, but when I try using the authorization code the file does not upload; the application does not report an error.

The code that follows contains both methods:

```
dbx = get_dbx_with_token()
```

works, but

```
dbx = get_dbx_with_auth_code()
```

does not. Any help appreciated.

```
import webbrowser

from dropbox import Dropbox
from dropbox.files import WriteMode
from dropbox import DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect

APP_KEY = '<my app key>'
APP_SECRET = '<my app secret>'
APP_TOKEN = '<my app token>'

def upload(dbx):
    local_file = '<path to local file>'
    remote_file = '<remote file name>'
    with open(local_file, 'rb') as f_upload:
        try:
            foo = dbx.files_upload(f_upload.read(), remote_file, 
                                   mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
            print('done ...', foo)
        except:
            print('Upload error')

def get_dbx_with_auth_code():
    auth_flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
    authorize_url = auth_flow.start()
    webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
    auth_code = input('Authorization code: ').strip()
    try:
        oauth_result = auth_flow.finish(auth_code)
    except:
        print('Token error')
        return None
    dbx = Dropbox(oauth_result.access_token)
    return dbx

def get_dbx_with_token():
    dbx = Dropbox(APP_TOKEN)
    return dbx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbx = get_dbx_with_token()
    #dbx = get_dbx_with_auth_code()
    upload(dbx)
```

The dbx.files_upload function (foo) returns:

```
 FileMetadata(
      name='uploaded.txt', 
      id='id:<my_id>', 
      client_modified=datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 13, 18, 24, 15), 
      server_modified=datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 13, 18, 24, 15), 
      rev='013000000010ede3870', size=6, path_lower='/upload test/uploaded.txt', 
      path_display='/upload test/uploaded.txt', 
      parent_shared_folder_id=None, 
      media_info=None, 
      symlink_info=None, 
      sharing_info=None, 
      property_groups=None, 
      has_explicit_shared_members=None, content_hash='<content hash>')
```

the FileMetadata for get_dbx_with_token is different:

```
parent_shared_folder_id='1234567890', 
sharing_info=FileSharingInfo(read_only=False,
parent_shared_folder_id='1234567890',
modified_by='dbid:AAAyXwp1wvSzPzmqzCJ9SWFuxhc')
```

(BTW the folder I am uploading to is shared folder belonging to another user)

The reason that I think it does not work is that it does not appear in my (browser) Dropbox folder if I use get_dbx_with_auth_code(), but it does if I use get_dbx_with_token().

Comment: Do you get any output at all? I see you have a few print statements, but you're not actually printing out any exceptions that you're catching in your `except` blocks. Try printing those to see what may be failing.

Comment: @Greg I get 'done ...' in the upload() try block!

Comment: It sounds like `files_upload` completed successfully then. What makes you think this isn't working? Try printing out the return value of `files_upload` to see the uploaded file metadata.

Comment: The FileMetData looks OK

Comment: I've updated the question with extra information.

Comment: The output indicates that the file was successfully uploaded, so it sounds like you're looking in a different folder or account when looking for it on the Dropbox web site. Double check what account/folder you're looking in. Also, you may be using a different app between the two flows, so note that if an app has the "app folder" permission, it will upload into the special "app folder" made for the app, by default inside "/Apps".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg's comments I realise that the upload was in fact taking place, but my limited understanding of the API meant that I didn't realise that using the auth_code option placed the file in a specific folder for the app. That's fine now that I know where to look for it.

> The output indicates that the file was successfully uploaded, so it sounds like you're looking in a different folder or account when looking for it on the Dropbox web site. Double check what account/folder you're looking in. Also, you may be using a different app between the two flows, so note that if an app has the "app folder" permission, it will upload into the special "app folder" made for the app, by default inside "/Apps"

Printing the output of `files_upload` showed what was going on.